# How do I set up an add-in catalog on office 365

Tags: sharepoint, add-in

I have been working through the following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn574752.aspx

I get to point 2. "In the left task pane, choose add-ins'

But in my sharepoint online admin I do not have this option.

From Office 365 I click Admin and go in to the Office 365 admin center.
Then down the left is the Admin section with Exchange, Skype, SharePoint, Compliance etc.  I click on SharePoint.

Then the options are Site collections, InfoPath, user profiles, bcs, term store, records management, search, secure store, apps, settings, configure hybrid.   There is no option called 'Add-in'.

I thought maybe the apps option might work / be the same thing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, it seems that the apps option is the same.  Just some inconsistency going on here.  The bit I actually got wrong was I opened Excel Online without launching it through the app launcher WITHIN office 365 itself and so Excel was not connected to SharePoint.

Comment: The plot thickens - I can open my Add-In fine, but I can't open my Excel Template it downloads it direct to Excel.  So you can't open a template file in Excel online.  You can only open a .xls file

Answer (score 0):

glad you were able to get the add-in to load from the catalog. The name is going through a change from "Apps for Office" to Office add-ins as the note in the link above says.

For the second part of the question, the Excel file should open directly from downloading the workbook from the internet. I would make sure you can open other .xlsx files. Also note to run Office web add-ins you need Office 2013 or above.